# Indian Latitude Longitude values

Tags: postgis, data

I am in need of around 10000 and odd Indian latitude and longitude values for my openlayers project. I have to load them in a postgis db. so a sql file or atleast text file would be better than a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a nice problem for OGR's python interface. This is my attempt, using [world.shp](http://www.aprsworld.net/gisdata/world/uncompressed/). Here's my code snippet:

```
from osgeo import ogr # Import ogr
import random # Random number generators etc.

g = ogr.Open ("world.shp") # Open the shapefile with all the world's countries
# Loop over the different features until we find INDIA.
for feat in g.GetLayer(0):
    if feat.GetFieldAsString("NAME").find ("INDIA") >= 0:
        break # We found India, break out of the loop. 
              # feat now holds the feature of INDIA

geom = feat.GetGeometryRef() # Get the geometry of Indina
( lon_min, lon_max, lat_min, lat_max ) = geom.GetEnvelope() # Now get the envelope

n_points = 0 # A counter
india_lon = [] # A list where we'll store longitudes within India
india_lat = [] # A list where we'll store latitudes within India
while n_points < 1000: # Until we reach our required number of points...
    # Draw random longitudes and latitudes within the envelope
    r_lon = random.random()*(lon_max - lon_min ) + lon_min
    r_lat = random.random()*(lat_max - lat_min ) + lat_min
    # Create a point geometry
    pt = ogr.Geometry( ogr.wkbPoint )
    pt.SetPoint_2D( 0, r_lon, r_lat )
    # Is this geometry within india?
    if pt.Within ( geom ):
        # yes! Store the latitude&longitude and update counter
        india_lon.append ( r_lon )
        india_lat.append ( r_lat )
        n_points = n_points + 1
# Save to a CSV file
fp=open("india.txt", 'w' )
fp.write( "Longitude, Latitude\n" )# Header
for (lon, lat) in zip (india_lon, india_lat):
    fp.write ("%f,%f\n" % ( lon, lat ) )

fp.close()
```

And here's how the result looks like:
[image: One thousand random points over India]

*Not* the most efficient way of dealing with this, but nice to learn :)

Comment: Very nice. Regarding efficiency, you aren't too far off. If you replace OGR with Shapely's [prepared geometry](http://sgillies.net/blog/869/efficient-batch-operations-for-shapely/) of India, the result is very impressive. 10k points within India are created in 1.125 sec (vs. nearly 2 min for OGR), a 105x speed-up!

Comment: Mmmm... True, I guess it does help a lot to prepare such a complex (multi)polygon. Can you use prepared geometries directly from OGR? I don't seem to find any references to it, I guess the GEOS prepared geometries stuff is not exposed to OGR...

Comment: Yeah, OGR generally exposes only a small part of GEOS. Shapely exposes much more of GEOS, and in my opinion is much more "pythonic". You definitely need OGR to read the Shapefile, but after that I use Shapely for more sophisticated GEOS work.

Comment: Here is my version of the script: http://pastebin.com/k57u01ay feel free to use it in any way you want

Comment: url given to world.shp is asking for authentication credential. you can download shp file from here http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

Comment: if you face problem in install gdl on mac, follow this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/212294

Answer (score 5):

You can generate 10000 random points within a polygon of India. There has been some recent work to do this:

- [Random Points in Polygon in JTS (Martin Davis' blog)](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2010/05/random-points-in-polygon-in-jts.html)
- [Random Point in Polygon for PostGIS (PostGIS wiki)](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UserWikiRandomPoint)

---

**Update** I've added a set-returning function to the [PostGIS User's wiki](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UserWikiRandomPoint#RandomPointsinPolygon), where I've used this question as an example. See that page for details. Although PostGIS also uses a prepared geometry, it isn't as fast as Shapely. My best speed for 10k points is 3023 ms (compared with 1125 ms for Shapely for same problem).

Comment: I am thankful for ur reply. Can you please guide how to execute that function in http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UserWikiRandomPoint and also how the input be given

Comment: I haven't had the chance to review the PostGIS functions yet (they are fresh). Start by adding the `RandomPoint` and `RandomPointMulti` functions into PostGIS (by running the SQL), then try something like `SELECT RandomPoint(india_poly.geom) FROM india_poly`, where `india_poly` is a 1-row geometry table with a polygon of India.