# Installing GDAL on MacOSX?

Tags: gdal, installation, ogr, mac, homebrew

Does anybody know what's the easiest way to install GDAL 2.0 on a MacOSX?

The usual suspects [kingchaos binary distribution](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) and [homebrew](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnMac) seem to be stuck on GDAL 1.11

I need support for TopoJSON feature properties that seem to have been included in [2.0](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5870)

**EDIT 2017/01/07:** [kingchaos binary distribution](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) provides now the GDAL 2.1 distribution

Comment: The only solutions is to wait or to try to compile GDAL yourself.

Comment: @gene thanks... I have no problem in building it from source... I'm wondering if there is any particular reason binaries are not available yet... Does GDAL 2.0 have any known issues? Can anybody shed some light? I'm surprised that 5 weeks have passed since 2.0 was released and there's no binary packaging yet...

Comment: maybe holidays ?

Comment: I've installed TopoJSON on OS X easily enough, and have converted JSON or SHP to TopoJSON. I don't see a need to have it part of GDAL.

Comment: I need the reverse path: from TopoJSON to SHP, and keep the feature properties (this is what is missing in GDAL1.11)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So far

```
brew install gdal --HEAD
```

resulted in

```
$ ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 2.1.0dev, released 2015/99/99
```

Comment: `1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: @Sant Have more information about your error?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO homebrew will be best/easiest, once their build issues are fixed. They are on the case, so if you have a GitHub account you may want to subscribe to notifications on the relevant issue - that way you'll know the moment it is available: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/42845

I just tried the Python easy_install route and it blew up my meagre 4GB RAM - so I'll be waiting for the brew formula..

**Edit - August 2016**

Homebrew now has a specific formula for GDAL 2+ `gdal-20` which right now installs GDAL v2.1.0

Comment: The gdal-20 Formula is in an external branch. Install with `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/master/Formula/gdal-20.rb`

Comment: That link is now broken. @Density21.5

Comment: No working. Any update for GDAL 3+?

Answer (score 3):

As @Deo_Leung reported, the [OSGeo Github](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac) is your friend. But it is even easier:

```
  brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac
  #brew search gdal (if you want to see the various available versions)
  brew install gdal2
```

Start it and grab a coffee, as it is doing a real `make` behind the scene ;-)

Check as well the output to add the correct symlinks

Comment: can you add the commands to add the symlinks?

Comment: This is subject to change depending on the version. Just read the output of brew install carefully, it is pretty straight forward :)

Comment: Except when it doesn't tell you what to run...

Comment: I needed to do 'brew link --force gdal2'

Answer (score 1):

see [OSGeo github](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac) for full detail

in short, as @Density commented(though his link has some wired characters):

`brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/master/Formula/gdal-20.rb`

and probably you need to do the following for further usage

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/gdal-20/bin
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gdal-20/lib
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gdal-20/include`

Comment: The link is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here:
[GDAL install on Mac: pip doesn't see gdal.h](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221770/gdal-install-on-mac-pip-doesnt-see-gdal-h/221785)

Essentially, there is an error in the gdal-py2.7.pth file in the latest version of GDAL. The best way to correct it is to compile the GDAL bindings using the special commands provided in the thread.

To compile yourself the Python bindings, download the [GDAL 2.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/2.1.0) python module and

```
python setup.py build_ext -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Headers -L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/unix/lib -lgdal
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Could you include the commands in your answer as links could become lost and render this answer useless

Comment: Sure thing, post now edited