# How to force PostGIS to use a specific GDAL version in Mac?

Tags: postgis, gdal

I am using PostGIS 2.5.4 on PostgreSQL 12.4 under macOS 10.13 environment.
Although GDAL version 2.4 is already installed in "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions", the query

```
select PostGIS_GDAL_Version();
```

returns

```
"GDAL 2.0.1, released 2015/09/15 GDAL_DATA not found"
```

How can I point PostGIS to the proper version of GDAL? And, incidentally, should the "GDAL_DATA not found" message be fixed and how?

Comment: I believe that it's looking for an environment variable called `GDAL_DATA` that you could try to set. However, you may have more luck installing with homebrew according to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155403/installing-gdal-on-macosx

Comment: see page 97 here: https://download.osgeo.org/postgis/docs/postgis-2.5.4.pdf